# Error when adding bootstrap 4 JS file to Wordpress Theme - Memory Exhausted

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4, wordpress-theming

I am new to using Wordpress. I am trying to integrate in bootstrap 4 to a custom theme. I can add the bootstrap css files in ok, but when I add the javaScript references I get an error

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wrfguides\wp-includes\cache.php on line 123

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

Heres my function:

```
function bs_wrfguides_scripts()
{

    /*CSS Files*/

    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('mainStyles', get_stylesheet_uri());

    /*JS Files*/
    wp_enqueue_script('fontAwesome', '//kit.fontawesome.com/7b645fb6eb.js', NULL, '5.12.1', true);
    wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.4.1', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bs_wrfguides_scripts');
```

The file is only 59k so I don't understand why this is an issue. If I comment out this line

```
 wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.4.1', true);
```

Then the error goes away. Whats happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try changing

`wp_enqueue_scripts('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.4.1', true);`

With

`wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '4.4.1', true);`

wp_enqueue_scripts is a hook which is being triggered when you enqueue a script https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/ and looks like you made a typo by using the name of the hook instead of the function.

Comment: The answer I was searching for.
this is the right solution provided by @nick-surmanidze